# Документ, который хранит backgroundColor не обновляется после смены цвета через js

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

У меня есть див, который имеет backgroundColor.
Я создаю переменную и помещаю туда этот див. После чего я делаю проверку на цвет фона и спокойно изменяю его.
Проблема в том, что после изменения цвета дива, этот цвет как бы не обновляется в информации html-документа и после очередного вызова функции цвет не меняется.
В чём ошибка?

```js
function colorChange(){
var ColorVar = document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0];

    if(ColorVar.style.backgroundColor='#000')
        {
         ColorVar.style.backgroundColor='#fff';
        }
    else
        {
        ColorVar.style.backgroundColor='#000';
        }

}
```

```css
.block{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" style="background-color: #000;">
 </div>
<button id="btn" onclick="colorChange();">
 Начать
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратить внимание на "===".

```
if ((ColorVar.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(0, 0, 0)"))
```